# Resource request for experimental physics and data handling

Tags: resource-recommendations, error-analysis, statistics, experimental-technique, data-analysis

When solving questions in olympiad physics, I come across problems on experiments, data, errors, drawing graphs and extracting information from given graphs, etc. Is there any good book/resource for learning how to approach these problems and specific things to keep in mind like conventions and such?

Comment: A good resource is grad school... :)

Comment: @Gilbert, I am effectively homeschooled.

Comment: if you’re doing Olympiad questions, presumably you’re in high school. My comment was made in jest.